# How to get the number of checkboxes that can be checked?

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I have a activity which contains 3 different `CheckBox`. Now I want to validate that at least 2 `CheckBox` must be selected but I am not able to achieve this. Please help.

Code:

```
Boolean checkPC = chkProtectMoney.isChecked();
Boolean checkGM = chkGrow_my_money.isChecked();
Boolean checkMN = chkMedicalNeeds.isChecked();


if(!(checkPC && checkGM == true) || !(checkGM && checkMN == true) || !(checkPC && checkMN == true) || !(checkPC && checkGM && checkPC == true)){

   Toast.makeText(getActivity(),R.string.two_expertise_caution,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Comment: why not simply use counter for that purpose ?

Comment: why condition is like that? O.O shouldn't be `if((checkPC && checkGM) || (checkGM && checkMN) || (checkPC && checkMN))` ? what are those `!` for?

Answer (score 4):

```
private boolean checkIfAnyTwoAreChecked() {
    int sum = 0;

    if(checkbox1.isChecked()){ sum++; }

    if(checkbox2.isChecked()){ sum++; }

    if(checkbox3.isChecked()){ sum++; }

    return sum >= 2;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can Use a `int` count .

```
 private int getCheckedCount() {
    int count = 0;
    if (checkBox1.isChecked())
        count++;
    if (checkBox2.isChecked())
        count++;
    if (checkBox3.isChecked())
        count++;
    return count;
}

  if(getCheckedCount()>=2){
    // Do your stuff
}
```

OR

```
 if(checkBox1.isChecked() && checkBox2.isChecked()
            || checkBox1.isChecked() && checkBox3.isChecked() 
            || checkBox2.isChecked() && checkBox3.isChecked()){
        // Do stuff
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your conditional statement to this

```
if((checkPC && checkGM) || (checkGM && checkMN) || (checkPC && checkMN)) {
    // YOUR CODE
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add checkedChangeListener for all checkboxes and update count based on check as in

```
int checkedCount = 0;

chkProtectMoney.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        if ( isChecked )
        {
            checkedCount++;
        }else{
           checkedCount--;
        }
        if(checkedCount >= 2){
           // voila
        }else{
           //alert to check atleast two
        }
    }
});
//add for other two same logic then
```